# Scalable update of java collections

Tags: java, algorithm, collections, scalability

I have a list of baskets. Each basket contains 30 items. I also have a list of purchase history containing items that was bought on a particular day, regardless of who bought it. The data looks like the following:

Basket1: item1, item2, item3, item4 .. item30

Day1: item_x1, item_x2, item_x3 .... item_xn

The total number of baskets is 4000. The total number of distinct items is 15000.

I want to score each day based on the probability of baskets that dominate a particular day.

```
p(basket_1|day_1) = p(basket1_item1|day_1) * p(basket1_item2|day_1) * p(basket1_item3|day_1) * ...* p(basket1_item30|day_1) ---> (Formula 1)
```

the probability of an item given a particular day is smoothed. In other words, must be calculated regardless of whether the item was bought at that particular day or not.

This is done for all baskets over all days. I would like to speed up the processing time and my current approach is the following:

1- Score all items for each particular day (the 15000 items) regardless of whether they occur on that day or not. The number of items bought every day is smaller than this (800 items on average) but since all these calculation are needed I do them all once.

2- Iterate over each item (t) and do the following:

a- Check for every basket (b) if that item is in it, if *b* contains *t* then:

a.1 Update the basket by calculating Formula 1 above and don't check or do anything with this basket again.

Items scores are stored in

```
 TObjectDoubleHashMap<String> itemScore;
```

Baskets scores are stored in

```
 TObjectDoubleHashMap<String> basketScore;
```

To update a basket, I do the following:

```
            Iterator<String> itr=baskets.get(basket).iterator();
            String item=null;
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                    item=itr.next();
                    sum+= itemScore.get(item);
            }
            sum= sum / (baskets.get(basket).size() * 1.00d);
            basketScore.put(basket, sum);
```

I'm curious if there is a more efficient method to do the update or tackle this task in general.

Comment: Questions regarding improving efficiency might be better suited here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Code it, profile it, see if you have a problem.  Fix it if you do; leave it if you don't.  How fast or efficient must it be?  Decide that first.  Likely to be a nano-optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to speed things up by using some smart data structures.

For example:

```
Map<Item, List<Basket>> basketsForItems; // populate for all baskets

Map<Basket, Integer> basketCount; // populate with 0 for all baskets
```

Then for each item you just do:

```
for (Basket b: basketsForItems.get(item)) {
   basketCount.put(basket, basketCount.get(basket)+1);
}
```

Hashcode lookups should be a lot faster than scanning lists all the time.

Obviously this is simplified as it doesn't look at your rules about days etc but hopefully you can get the idea.

Comment: Tim, Thank you for your suggestion. I agree with you that your suggestion is better than what I've done and indeed it did speed up the process nicely.

Comment: @DotNet happy to help. Most of the time organising your data right is the key to optimisation. If the answer helped don't forget to accept it :)

Comment: Accepted, after multithreading the task, it scaled to a reasonable speed. Thanks.